# Primitive elements in Hopf algebras over the integers

Tags: lie-algebras, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra over $\mathbb Z$, and assume that $H$ is cocommutative, graded, generated in degree $1$, and connected (its degree-$0$ part is $\mathbb Z$).

Are there nice, natural conditions that will enforce that $H$ is a universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra over $\mathbb Z$?

For example, if $H$ is $\mathbb Z$-free, then the Milnor-Moore theorem implies $H\otimes\mathbb Q=U(P)$ for $P'$ the space of primitives in $H\otimes\mathbb Q$, and presumably $P'=P\otimes\mathbb Q$ for $P$ the $\mathbb Z$-module of primitives in $H$.

I'm sure this works in a much more general setting, but I failed to locate relevant papers or books on Hopf algebras over non-fields.

Note that this question is related to the MO question
[Integral Milnor-Moore theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363288/integral-milnor-moore-theorem), though it seems orthogonal.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Frédéric Patras had a paper on this. He required some divided powers structure on $H$.

Comment: Ah, no, that was for the Leray theorem (which is philosophically dual to Cartier-Milnor-Moore, but not in a tangibly useful way).